# В Android Studio нет поля Generate Signed APK

Tags: android-studio

Установил Android Studio установил Cordova запускаю на своем телефоне приложение отлично все работает. Запускаю на эмуляторе тоже все работает. Но по какой то причине у меня не отображается Build - Generate Signed APK

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вообще очень мало активных полей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким и какие есть идеи?

Comment: Судя по всему, теперь это называется Build Bundle /APK. Второй пункт сверху.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Одним из решений есть создание APK из консоли:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

и потом для самого создания инсталлера:

```
$ cordova build --release
```

дальше у вас будет приложение но оно будет не подписанным и будет называться как-то так:

```
app-release-unsigned.apk
```

для того чтобы его подписать вам необходимо сначала сделать ключ и потом этим ключом подписать свое приложение:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore android.keystore -alias 
android-app-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

подписываем приложение:

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore android.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk android-app-key
```

так же постарайтесь не забыть свой alias и keystore потому что у вас это спросят:

```
# if zipalign is not installed
$ sudo apt install zipalign
$ zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk
```

и в итоге у вас будет такой файлик:

```
app-release.apk
```

Удачи :)